# Use iCloud as working directory in Pycharm

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, icloud

I want to access some data stored on the iCloud Drive. I'm currently using Pycharm as my code interpreter. I'm able to access files stored in OneDrive by changing my working directory, but I'm not able to do the same with iCloud. One solution is to move all the data from iCloud to OneDrive, but that seems inefficient. Somebody who can help me with this?

Comment: What specific issue are you trying to solve? How do you want to access this data? Are you trying to access it through Python? You need more details before someone is able to help

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to access data from Excel .dat files stored in iCloud through Python. I’m using Pycharm as my code interpreter. The data is used as an input to a model I’m creating.

Comment: I don't believe there is an official way of doing this, although some unofficial libraries on github you can search for. This question & answer also has a few details on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043927/get-icloud-web-service-endpoints-to-fetch-data

Answer (score 1):

The iCloud Drive does not show up as part of the normal filesystem therefore the Pycharm file picker dialog can not access it. The best solution to your problem is to transfer the data from your iCloud Drive into your computer's hard drive.

Comment: Okey, thanks. Is there no way to work around this?

Comment: There is no way that I know of other than downloading the file to your computer